# Is there a way to get the DateTime shown on the Outlook Mail interface using VB.Net

Tags: vb.net, datetime, outlook

Is there a way I can get the date/time shown for every Mail Item in the Outlook app itself?

[image: This is the image of what I'm trying to retrieve.]

As you can see, the MailItem.ReceivedTime property shows a different value than the datetime shown on the Outlook application itself so I'm not sure if I can use this property to fit my requirement. Is it possible to get this using VB.Net?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: I believe Outlook shows the **Sent** time in the top-right corner, not the ReceivedTime.

Comment: @Dai I just checked its SentOn Property and its value is 7/30/2020 9:07:46 AM. Just a 3 second difference from the ReceivedTime. I also checked the other properties like CreationTime and LastModificationTime and they didn't match that 9:08 AM in the image.

Comment: I think the `9:08` value is from the `SentOn` property being rounded-up to the nearest minute.

Comment: @Dai That's it! I just did some tests and it really is rounding off to the nearest minute when the seconds goes 30 or more. How do I vote your answer?

Comment: I've reposted my comments as an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Desktop Outlook shows the Message **Sent** date+time in the top-right corner of the message preview pane, not the Received date+time.
- Additionally, the value is rounded to the closest minute, so `09:07:46` will be rendered as `09:08`

  - <sub>Personally, I feel this is **completely wrong**: date+time values should always be rounded down.</sub>